# Como incluir vários RadioButton?

Tags: java, android, radiobutton

Estava interessado em fazer um APP com 30 questões de perfil de personalidade, onde cada questão terá duas alternativas de escolha. Pensei em usar o `RadioButton`, mas como são 30 questões não gostaria de incluí-las todas na tela de uma só vez,  gostaria de exibir somente uma questão com duas alternativas e a cada seleção de uma das alternativas já chamasse a outra questão.

Isso é possível fazer sem criar 30 *activities*?

Eu não queria criar essa quantidade de *activities*, mas se não tiver jeito, vai ser isso mesmo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parto do principio que está a falar de Apps para android...

Pode por exemplo ter as perguntas e respostas possíveis em arrays, quando a pessoa responder carrega num botão "seguinte", que actualiza os valores conforme o array.